# Mixed Model [in place of Repeated Measures ANOVA], but need RANKED Tukey results PER sampling date (NOT overall)

Tags: r, rank, mixed-models, tukey

> I have data from 6 different treatments, with sampling repeated 8
>   times over 3 years (no missing data points). My individual bins from
>   each treatment are equally split in 7 randomly distributed blocks. To
>   analyze, I am using a Mixed Model (nlme package).

***Example of the data :***

```
bin     treatment   Bloc        date        CONTAM
b1      TR_A            1       t0      4.753038458
b2      TR_A            2       t0      4.709589136
b3      TR_A            3       t0      4.72668357
b4      TR_A            4       t0      4.647430928
b5      TR_A            5       t0      4.670129151
b6      TR_A            6       t0      4.647430928
b7      TR_A            7       t0      4.811256762
b8      TR_B            1       t0      4.551238194
b9      TR_B            2       t0      4.662660293
b10     TR_B            3       t0      4.753038458
b11     TR_B            4       t0      4.69554541
b12     TR_B            5       t0      4.69554541
```

Packages used:

```
nlme ; lattice ; nortest ; multcomp
```

Here is the script I am currently using:

```
mod.lme=lme(CONTAM~Treatment*date,random=~1|bloc/bin,data=data)
summary(mod.lme)
anova(mod.lme)
summary(glht(mod.lme, linfct=mcp(Treatment = "Tukey")), test = adjusted(type = "bonferroni"))
```

This works just fine (ANOVA<0.001) but is not giving me the information I need.

-> I obtain an ***overall*** Tukey, but since I am dealing with degradation data I expect the treatments to be similar at the beginning and end, but DIFFERENT in the middle.

> ----> Therefore, I am seeking a test that will give me the RANKED (a, ab,
>   bc...) Tukey results PER sampling date, while taking in consideration
>   that this is a repeated measures model.

Any ideas? :)

Thanks!

---

---

---

FYI, I've attempted the solutions from this question: [post hoc test for a two way mixed model anova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831447/post-hoc-test-for-a-two-way-mixed-model-anova)

## 1

```
library(GAD)
snk.test(mod.lme, term="Treatment*date", among="Treatment", within="date")
```

My inconclusive result : #  Error in object$model[, 2:(length(object$x) + 1)] : incorrect number of dimensions

## 2

This second one gives me a huge output, but not the one I need.

```
library(lsmeans)
summary(lsmeans(mod.lme, pairwise~Treatment*date), infer=TRUE)
```

Comment: In the `lsmeans` call, specify `pairwise ~ Treatment | date`. If you look at `vignette("using-lsmeans")`, you can find out all sorts of things you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Obtain the LS means:

```
library("lsmeans")
mod.lsm <- lsmeans::lsmeans(mod.lme, ~ Treatment * date)
```

(Calling `lsmeans::lsmeans` prevents it from using the same function in the **lmerTest** package, if it happens to be loaded.)

List the LS means:

```
mod.lsm
```

Do pairwise comparisons, separately for each `date`:

```
pairs(mod.lsm, by = "date")
```

(The default result shows $t$ tests and adjusted $P$ values using the Tukey method.)

Comment: This is great in the sense that it does indeed split the results by date!:) >Unfortunately, they are not ranked, making the results difficult to interpret with my 6 treatments (15lines/date=120lines to interpret). <br/> Example of the result:<br/>date = t0:<br/>contrast        estimate         SE df t.ratio p.value<br/>TR_B-TR_A   -0.221575173 0.06832637 30  -3.243  0.0313<br/>TR_C-TR_A  -0.170258301 0.06832637 30  -2.492  0.1586<br/>TR_D-TR_A   -0.142952834 0.06832637 30  -2.092  0.3182<br/>Would you happen to have a way to organize this with a ranking method?
THANKS! :)

Comment: Sorry for the long paragraph! I haven't figured out how to code "enter/carriage return" yet. Hope it's clear enough?

Comment: I can't really read your comment on my phone. But perhaps you want to try this: `cld(mod.lsm)`. It creates a compact letter display, which displays the LS means in numerical order for each "by" level, along with grouping letters. To use this you need to also have the **multcompView** package installed.

Comment: We are getting somewhere! The cld(mod.lsm) code works, but it returns ranks comparing the 120 lines of data to each other, rather than grouping them by "Treatment" within the dates. Nonetheless, I can go through and extract the information myself within the dates easier than before.
Thanks again!